# Upgrade Magento-2.2.6 to 2.3.1

Tags: magento-2.3

When I upgarde magneto2 version 2.2.6 to 2.3.1 and when I run command `composer update`, I got this error :

```
Problem 1
    - magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 requires magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.1.1 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-metapackage[1.1.1].
    - magento/inventory-composer-metapackage 1.1.1 requires magento/inventory-composer-installer 1.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/inventory-composer-installer[1.1.0].
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.3.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.3.1].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In you composer.json file you have to edit the minimum stability to dev:

```
{
  "require": {      

  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```